# Replacing Windows XP with Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, windows-xp

I wish to create space on my computer, deleting XP permanently from my harddrive. I have only 2 partitions! due to the dualboot I installed without knowing exactly what I was getting into!

I cannot unmount it and fear there's no other exit strategy... I'd have to uninstall the whole lot again?

[image: screenshot of gparted]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of GParted (search for it in your Dash)?

Comment: Louis, yes I could do that, if I knew how :( i made the shot jus t don't know how to insert.

Comment: By default, Ubuntu asks you to save the screenshot somewhere. You can go to imgur.com to upload the saved screenshot and post the link to it here.

Comment: Louis, thanks for that. Here's the link http://i.imgur.com/YtCGWT2.png?1

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu using Wubi?

Comment: Louis, no I tried that, didnt work properly then installed directly frol the ubuntu site after the tour;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get rid of Windows, backup your personal data (Documents, Photos, Music, Videos) to an external device, create a ubuntu-boot-medium of your choice (dvd, usb drive) and select it during startup by selecting it as the startup-device. 
Then, choose 'install ubuntu' from the menu. The following steps should be pretty self-explanatory, provided that you've been able to install ubuntu alongside windows before.

Just in case, at one point, the installer will ask you:

- install ubuntu next to other operating systems
- erase disk and install ubuntu
- something else

Choose the second option. Everything will be taken care of.
Have fun,g

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to delete anything or start over.

Just boot to the Ubuntu live CD and run Try Ubuntu.

While there are many options you can choose from, one option is to run gparted and resize the two partitions to a small size (just over the size in use).  Move the two partitions so that they are next to each other.

Now make a a new partition of the extended type.  With the extended partition you can make any number of partitions you want.  Make one for your new Installation (the majority of the drive) and make one for your swap partition.  Depending on the amount of space you have available I'd try to have my swap partition about 4 gigs or equal the size of the amount of ram I have.  (Other swap size recommendations: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq

Now run the Ubuntu Installation option and specify "Something Else" for the install option.  Specify the new partition you've just created for your new Ubuntu installation.

When it finishes you'll have boot options for each of the OS installation you have.  You can now mount those other partitions that you referenced not wanting and backup any important data you have on them.  After your desired data is backed up, you can delete those partitions using gparted.